# Introducing Kernel hang for debugging purposes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any way to make kernel hang or panic very early during bootup process, i.e.,while executing `start_kernel` function. Currently I am using `while(1);` in `start_kernel` function to hang the kernel. But I want to use real case scenarios where kernel might hang or panic such as by **Enabling/Disabling some config in menuconfig**. This is for understanding and applying various kernel debugging solutions for kernel hang.

Comment: Declare a pointer variable and assign NULL or "0xDEADBEEF", then dereference the pointer.

Comment: @Jeyaram Will kernel hang or will it crash? I want hang, not crash or panic.

Comment: kernel panics or crash !!

Comment: I suggest to read https://lwn.net/Articles/209257/ and  about "kprobes".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add a kernel panic without using any pointers and just with the use of `panic("Message")` function wherever we wanted the panic to test.